# ng-model with checkbox does'nt work inside <span>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this doesn't work?

```
 <span class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" ng-repeat="team in teams">
        <label class="checkbox btn btn-primary" for="{{team.id}}">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pageData.selection[team.id]" name="group" id="{{team.id}}">{{team.name}}
        </label>
 </span>
```

But this one without `<span` works correctly.

```
    <label class="checkbox btn btn-primary"  ng-repeat="team in teams">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="pageData.selection[team.id]">{{team.name}}
    </label>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working. You could use a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/) to demonstrate?

Comment: What does `data-toggle="buttons"` do? Could it be that which is causing an issue. It's unlikely that a span is causing the issue.

Comment: @BenCr you are right. That was a problem. data-toggle="buttons" hides checkbox, so it looks like default button.

Comment: Did you figure out how to get this to work with the data-toggle="buttons"?  I'm trying to do the same thing and I had to resort to not using the button styles so it makes my group look like checkboxes.